# Working with JSON in iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, json

I have worked with JSONKit library in a previous iOS version. The problem with JSONKit in iOS6 is that most of the methods are deprecated and I am getting warnings when I compile.

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have got another solution for the same...

Following link contains:

- JSONKit.h
- JSONKit.m

[ios-funda.blogspot.in/2012/11/working-with-json-in-ios6.html](http://ios-funda.blogspot.in/2012/11/working-with-json-in-ios6.html)

This JSONKit classes worked fine with iOS6..

Answer (score 4):

Use the native [NSJONSerialization Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, here's a repo with iOS6 fixes (and a Podspec file). https://github.com/JoistApp/JSONKit